# How do I open a command prompt as a regular user (not an adminstrator)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, powershell

I'm trying to fire up a regular command prompt to test the limitations of certain commands. However, whenever I open the Command Prompt from the start menu, it automatically runs as Administrator. If I use the Run dialog, it automatically runs all commands as an administrator as well.

I looked into the Command Prompt properties (in the start menu). While there is a "run as administrator" option, it is unchecked... but it's happening regardless.

[image: Command Prompt Properties, Advanced Options showing Run As Administrator is disabled.]

Is there a way to do this without logging out and back in on a normal user account? (As an aside, I'm having the exact same problem in PowerShell... either/both would be great to run as a standard account at this point..)

Comment: So it sounds like you are logged into the machine with an account that has admin priveleges.

Comment: What is your UAC setting?

Comment: @DavidMarshall "Never notify." Hmm.... I think you may have spotted the culprit.

Comment: Is this your personal computer, or a work computer (on a domain)? Any local or group policies set?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 This is a work computer, attached to a domain... I don't see any local or group policies that might change the behavior, but then again I don't really know my way around there. If there's a particular place I should be looking, I'd be happy to check.

Comment: To clarify, your CMD prompts open with `Administrator: ` at the start of the title, correct?

Comment: If UAC is off, you only get the administrator security token. Normally an administrator account gets two tokens; one is equivalent to a standard user token, the other unfiltered token is only used when elevated for example when using Run as administrator. If you can, try turning on UAC.

Comment: @DavidMarshall You got it. That was the problem, and you provided the solution.

Comment: By coincidence I was watching this http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2014/WIN-B411

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are on a work domain, it may be Group Policies set by the network admin (to control UAC) that's causing this.

Run `GPResult /H c:\temp\blah.html` on your workstation, and then open the HTML file and look for policies starting with "User Account Control" to see if any are enabled.

These should be under `Computer Configuration -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options`.

The main one that sticks out to me is "User Account Control: Behavior of the elevation prompt for administrators in Admin Approval Mode", as it can be configured as such:

> Elevate without prompting: Allows privileged accounts to perform an operation that requires elevation without requiring consent or credentials. Note: Use this option only in the most constrained environments.

If that's set then it's probably what causing it, and you'll have to discuss with the network admin to have a different policy applied to your computer.

Comment: For the record, I tried looking into the results as suggested, but lo and behold,  there there was no "user account control" section in it -- at all. The User Account Control Settings I accessed from the start menu *are* set to "never notify", and I temporarily switched it to the second-lowest setting, clicked OK, ran the command again, and re-ran the report... no changes. I probably need to reboot my computer now to check for changes.

Comment: GPResult shows you the Group Policies that are configured and applied to the computer, changing the local UAC setting is unrelated to that report.  Since you are in a company with IT support, have you asked them about it yet?

Comment: I was avoiding it until I was certain it was something I couldn't remedy. When I turned UAC back on (to its minimal setting), my command prompts started opening in a standard mode again. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are logged as user with admin privileges, it's normal and expected behavior. You can only go level up by "Run as administrator". If you want to test commands with lower privileges, try to create guest account.

For exploring privileges per process, it's nice to see it in [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/sk-sk/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) in process properties. There you can see in Security tab approved groups your account is belong to, or thread permissions.

Comment: "If you are logged as user with admin privileges, it's normal and expected behavior." - It's not.  By default, Windows does not open command prompts in admin mode, even for admin users.